# LateX: Equation Like "box" for a block of text

Tags: latex

Hi I'm using LateX. I have a block of text that I'd like to have a small box like space highlighting the are (just like a \begin{equation} but for text).

Is there such a thing in LateX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `\makebox` what you're looking for?

> To create boxes of text that behave differently from the rest of the text, we can use
>
> ```
> \makebox[width][pos]{text}
> ```
>
> The width sets the width the of the box. The `pos` sets the positioning of the text - either `r` (right justified text), `l` (left justified), or `s` (stretched to fill the box). If the `pos` parameter is left out, as in `\makebox[1in]{centerme}`, the text is centered. The text is placed in the box. If you want to draw a box around the text, use `\framebox` just as you would use `\makebox`.
>
> `\mbox{text}` and `\fbox{text}` are quick versions of `\makebox` and `\framebox`, which create a box to fit the size of the text.

There are some more examples at http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=LaTeX:Layout#Boxes

Comment: It's actually parbox[] that was shown in your article.  Is there something similar to parbox but also creates a border with the box?

Comment: (Not my article, just something I found on the web.) To create a border, maybe \framebox is what you want. To put the text inside, you might need to use a minipage, as John Wordsworth said.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking I'm afraid, but if you just want to indent text with a margin on each side of the page to make it stand out, you can use...

\begin{quotation}
  Quotation is good for long blocks of text that you want highlighted
\end{quotation}

\begin{quote}
  Quote is suited to a single block of quoted text.
\end{quote}

If you actually want to have a physical black box around the text, you might want to consider wrapping it in a tabular / table, or you might want to delve into minipages and/or par box environments...